# Filtering Groovy map by a list

Tags: dictionary, groovy, filter

In groovy is there a simple way to filter a map`s indexes by a list.

```
produce_map        = ["grapes":"fruit","apple":"fruit","tomato":"vegetable","peas:"vegetable"]
green_produce_list = ["grapes","apples",'peas']

<magic code>

//desired result
filterd_map = ['apple':'fruit','grapes':'fruit','peas':'vegetable']
```

Comment: What is `<magic code>`? What have you tried so far? Did you face any specific problem when trying to solve the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [subMap](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#subMap(java.lang.Object[])):

> Creates a sub-Map containing the given keys. This method is similar to List.subList() but uses keys rather than index ranges. The original map is unaltered.
>
> ```
> def orig = [1:10, 2:20, 3:30, 4:40]
> assert orig.subMap([1, 3] as int[]) == [1:10, 3:30]
> assert orig.subMap([2, 4] as Integer[]) == [2:20, 4:40]
> assert orig.size() == 4
> ```