# Get values from map by list of keys in groovy

Tags: list, dictionary, groovy, key

I have a list of strings, i would like to get values from a map, using this list of keys.

For example:

```
ListOfKeys = ["one", "two", "three"]
map =["one":1,"two":2,"three":3,"four":4]
```

I should get only the first three because they are in the map, the rest are not.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filtering Groovy map by a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58824147/filtering-groovy-map-by-a-list)

Answer (score 0):

```
ListOfKeys = ["one", "two", "three"]
map =["one":1,"two":2,"three":3,"four":4]

def values = ListOfKeys.collectEntries{ map[it] }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ListOfKeys = ["one", "two", "three"];
map =["one":1,"two":2,"three":3,"four":4];

result = ListOfKeys.collectEntries{[it,map[it]]}

println result
```